# Keras: Difference between AveragePooling1D layer and GlobalAveragePooling1D layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm a bit confused when it comes to the average pooling layers of Keras. [The documentation](https://keras.io/layers/pooling/) states the following:

> AveragePooling1D: Average pooling for temporal data.
>
> Arguments
>
> ```
> pool_size: Integer, size of the average pooling windows.
> strides: Integer, or None. Factor by which to downscale. E.g. 2 will halve the input. If None, it will default to pool_size.
> padding: One of "valid" or "same" (case-insensitive).
> data_format: A string, one of channels_last (default) or channels_first. The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.
> ```
>
> channels_last corresponds to inputs with shape (batch, steps,
>   features) while channels_first corresponds to inputs with shape
>   (batch, features, steps).
>
> Input shape
>
> ```
> If data_format='channels_last': 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, steps, features)
> If data_format='channels_first': 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, features, steps)
> ```
>
> Output shape
>
> ```
> If data_format='channels_last': 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, downsampled_steps, features)
> If data_format='channels_first': 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, features, downsampled_steps)
> ```

and

> GlobalAveragePooling1D: Global average pooling operation for temporal data.
>
> Arguments
>
> ```
> data_format: A string, one of channels_last (default) or channels_first. The ordering of the dimensions in the inputs.
> ```
>
> channels_last corresponds to inputs with shape (batch, steps,
>   features) while channels_first corresponds to inputs with shape
>   (batch, features, steps).
>
> Input shape
>
> ```
> If data_format='channels_last': 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, steps, features)
> If data_format='channels_first': 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, features, steps)
> ```
>
> Output shape
>
> 2D tensor with shape: (batch_size, features)

I (think that I) do get the concept of average pooling but I don't really understand why the GlobalAveragePooling1D layer simply drops the steps parameter. Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`GlobalAveragePooling1D` is same as `AveragePooling1D` with `pool_size=steps`. So, for each feature dimension, it takes average among all time steps. The output thus have shape `(batch_size, 1,  features)` (if `data_format='channels_last'`). They just flatten the second (or third if `data_format='channels_first'`) dimension, that is how you get output shape equal to  `(batch_size, features)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. That clarifies a lot. This easy explanation should be part of the Keras documentation.

Comment: how we can feed the input layer to  GlobalAveragePooling1D? `main_input = Input(shape=(None,), name='main_input')

x = keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D()(main_input)` ?